# Remove Additional image sizes created by theme

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I am using this code to remove additional image sizes created by theme which seems to work but I can still see 1 more size being generated when i upload an image.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
add_action('init', 'remove_plugin_image_sizes');

function remove_plugin_image_sizes() {
  remove_image_size('post-thumbnail');
  remove_image_size('entry');
  remove_image_size('entry-cropped');
  remove_image_size('entry-fullwidth');
  remove_image_size('entry-cropped-fullwidth');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [get_intermediate_image_sizes()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_intermediate_image_sizes)

It returns an array with all loaded image sizes.

Comment: sorry for being a noob but how can i test this please ?

Comment: No Problem, i'm a noob too. 

Just add var_dump(get_intermediate_image_sizes()); to the bottom of your functions.php. 

But be aware, it outputs the array on the Site, so just use if it's ok!